# Algorithm to compute mesh from intersection of infinite halfspaces

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry

Is there a simple algorithm to compute the convex polyhedron (as a mesh with verticies, edges, and faces) resulting from the intersection of a set of infinite halfspaces? This is essentially a CSG (constructive solid geometry) to B-rep (boundary representation) problem. I am aware that CGAL has the Nef-polyhedra capabilities, but using CGAL is way overkill and complicated.

The actual problem I have is this:
Given a 3D lattice specified by its 3 primitive lattice vectors, determine the Voronoi cell of a single lattice point.

The problem is that I actually need the polyhedral surface rather than just the volume, so I need a boundary representation.

Comment: Try [qhalf](http://www.qhull.org/html/qhalf.htm) from the [qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) package.

Comment: That's all well and good, but I'd like a description of how it does the computation. The manual mentions that by duality, it is reduced to a convex hull problem. I don't think I see how that is.

Comment: @VictorLiu It is not clear that you are looking for an algorithm or a tool. From title it looks like you are looking for an algorithm. But then you mention CGAL and CGAL is a tool.